# Integrating Stylelint with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, stylelint

I'm working on trying to integrate [stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint) into my freshly created Vue project.

I thought this would be a simple case of using the [Stylelint Webpack Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/stylelint-webpack-plugin/) but when I run `yarn serve`, any errors completely freeze it with no output. If I run `yarn build`, the build will fail as intended but will only print `"There was a stylelint error"`.

My `vue.config.js` is as follows:

```js
const stylelintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new stylelintPlugin({ files: ['**/*.(vue|scss)'] }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Here are my current versions from `package.json`:

```js
 "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
 "stylelint": "^10.1.0",
 "stylelint-config-recommended": "^2.2.0",
 "stylelint-scss": "^3.9.2",
```

Answer (score 25):

While this may come too late, here are working configurations by using `stylelint-config-recommended-scss`.

It is an extension to the 3rd party `stylelint-scss` plugin which needs to be installed along with `stylelint` itself. Also `stylelint-webpack-plugin` needs to be installed, which seems to have been missing from your setup.

Install dev dependencies:

```sh
# First remove an unnecessary one you had (with NPM):
npm uninstall stylelint-config-recommended

# Or with Yarn:
yarn remove stylelint-config-recommended

# Install dev deps with NPM:
npm i -D stylelint stylelint-scss stylelint-config-recommended-scss stylelint-webpack-plugin

# Or with Yarn:
yarn add -D stylelint stylelint-scss stylelint-config-recommended-scss stylelint-webpack-plugin
```

In your `vue.config.js` configuration file:

```js
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new StyleLintPlugin({
        files: ['src/**/*.{vue,scss}'],
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Create a file `stylelint.config.js` in your project's root folder:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: 'stylelint-config-recommended-scss',
  rules: {
    'selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown': [
      true,
      {
        ignorePseudoElements: ['v-deep']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

In `package.json` you can add this `lint:scss` command (run by `npm run lint:scss`). It tries to run autofix on all rules, but please note that not all rules can be autofixed.

In that case the script will output a list of error lines and exit on error. You need to go and fix these by hand, and then re-run the script to see that the errors got fixed:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint:scss": "stylelint ./src/**/*.{vue,scss} --fix"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! Please add a comment if I missed something.

Comment: Doesn't this require some vue-specific parser?

Answer (score 0):

my configuration is the same like ux.engineer written
but when i try run scripts `npm run lint:scss` then I have

```
node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/get-stdin/index.js:13
for await (const chunk of stdin) {
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

it turned out that I had the wrong (old) node version, so pay attention for that